# Chromium ignores the grammar set for speech recognition

Tags: google-chrome, speech-recognition, chromium, webspeech-api, webkitspeechrecognition

I'm using [SpeechRecognition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition) under Chromium (an interface of the [Web Speech API](https://w3c.github.io/speech-api/speechapi.html)) and have a [grammar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechGrammar) set for the recognition, defined in [JSGF](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-jsgf-20000605/):

```
"#JSGF V1.0 UTF-8; grammar animal_list; public <animal> = dog | cat | horse ;"
```

It is successfully added to the recognition, so I would except that it would only return one of the three words (dog, cat, or horse) when I speak, but instead it continues to recognize anything I say.

First I thought the issue was with my code, but then I found that Mozilla made a [live demo](http://mdn.github.io/web-speech-api/speech-color-changer/) that illustrates this very use case of the API: You tell something, and if it is one of the colors defined in the grammar, the API recognizes it. This is how it was supposed to work I think.

But look at the bottom of the page for diagnostics messages: Whatever you tell it, it recognizes. Not just those colors defined in the grammar. As if the grammar wouldn't be there at all.

What do you think, should I report this as a bug of Chrome/Chromium and if so, where? Or do I misunderstand something how it is to work?

Comment: They do not support grammars still.

Comment: Ok thanks, I posted a [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=799849), let's see if google does anything so the API conforms to W3C's recommendation

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev How is the present question a duplicate of the linked question?

Comment: In SpeechRecognition, you can set the maxAlternatives variable to a big integer, and loop through the results until you find the predefined answers. Example:
// Before calling start()
recognition.maxAlternatives = 100;

// in the onresult method
recognition.onresult = (event) { /* Loop through event.results */ }